# How to take user input in a format of <diceNumber>d<diceFace>-<cardToDeal> in java(for eg. 2d6-3)?

Tags: java

I want to take user input, so that they can enter values in a specific style

```
<diceNumber>d<diceFace>-<cardToDeal>
```

Then i have to extract (parse) each value from user input such as:

If user inputs 3d4-2 .
I have to store each value in different variables, such like below

```
int diceNumber = 3
int diceFaces = 4
int cardToDeal = 2
```

i had tried this,

```
int diceNumber;
int diceFaces;
int cardToDeal;
String input;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)
System.out.println("Enter dice notation!");
input = sc.nextLine();

String[] dice1 = input.split("d");
try{
   diceNum = Integer.parseInt(dice1[0]);
   String[] dice2 = dice1[1].split("-"); 
   diceFace = Integer.parseInt(dice2[0]);
   cardToDeal = Integer.parseInt(dice2[1]); 
}catch(NumberFormatException ae){
   System.out.println("You input invalid dice notation!");
}
```

it works for little but it isn't flexible. User should also able to inter only

```
<diceNumber>d<diceFace>
```

(for eg. 2d6)

Anyone can help me to make this little program flexible and fully validated.
If there is any short method to do it ??
I'm beginner in java so please help me and sorry for the bad English.

Comment: so add some `if` testing. "if there's more after reading dicefaces, process that too".

Comment: i'd tried using if case, by storing input string values in array of char( using toCharArray() ) and looping that array. But it is a long process, i want short process

Comment: parsing is always a long process, especially when you start adding support for "optional" things in the input.

Comment: ok! and thank you for giving me your time